# When defining an interface, do not add I at the beginning of the reminder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When using Visual Studio to write an C# interface, for example, I do this:

```
  public interface broker
  {

  }
```

The broker will remind you to add i in front, but now this reminder no longer appears.

How to make it appear again. I tried looking for similar settings in Code Style but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Code-style naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules), you can adjust the naming rules of the interface through editorconfig , please follow these steps:

1. Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and click "Add New Item", find editorconfig and create it.
2. Open editorconfig => Naming Style => interface => Make sure the Severity of the interface is Suggestion

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I followed your steps and found that it has been set to suggestion

Comment: @Fileter You can first set the Severity of the interface to Disable and press ctrl+s to save the setting. Then open editorconfig and set the Severity of the interface to Disable. Save the settings and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: Thancks, it's work